# Does this picture look wrong to anyone else?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, geometric-optics

There is a typo.  One which obfuscates the main point and makes it difficult for anyone unfamiliar with the problem to deduce the answer.

[image]

Comment: The *x* and arrow to the right that looks like a graph axis seems out of place.

Comment: No, that's fine, it's the x-axis.

Comment: And your point is *what*?  This is one specific diagram from one specific book.  Doesn't belong here, IMO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about a concept in physics. It's just a challenge to spot an error in a diagram from a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angles XCF and N'CB are marked as being the same angle, but that is clearly nonsense since that would makes line CB parallel to line FB.

Comment: It would make CB perpendicular to CF (which they are), I don't see the problem since one can clearly see relative to what lines the angles are defined.

Comment: In the triangle CBF the diagram as shown does indeed have CB perpendicular to CF, as is BF. So apparently the three angles in the triangle are $90^\circ $, $90^\circ $ and zero.

Comment: You got it.  The wrong angle is marked as 90 degrees.  The right angle is BCF not CFB.